# sed insert matching pattern in front of lines between patterns

Tags: regex, sed, multiline

I have de following text

> 1012 - ABC-DEF
>
> VIP
>
> Number
>
> Index
>
> Diagnosis
>
> Variant
>
> Hardware
>
> 2017-06-19 14:41:28

and I would like to append "1012 - ABC-DEF" to the beginning of every line between the two patterns "1012 - ABC-DEF" and "2017-06-19 14:41:28"

so the result would be:

> 1012 - ABC-DEF
>
> 1012 - ABC-DEF VIP
>
> 1012 - ABC-DEF Number
>
> 1012 - ABC-DEF Index
>
> 1012 - ABC-DEF Diagnosis
>
> 1012 - ABC-DEF Variant
>
> 1012 - ABC-DEF Hardware
>
> 2017-06-19 14:41:28

although I have the solution, I'm looking for a better one.

Here's my solution:

```
sed -i "/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\) - ABC-DEF/,/2017\-\([0-9][0-9]\)\-\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\)\:\([0-9][0-9]\)\:\([0-9][0-9]\)/{/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\) - ABC-DEF/n;/2017\-\([0-9][0-9]\)\-\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\)\:\([0-9][0-9]\)\:\([0-9][0-9]\)/!{s/^/1012 - ABC-DEF /g}}" *
```

what i want is if the text matches the pattern "1012 - ABC-DEF" it should automatically be filled in at {s/^/1012 - ABC-DEF /g}}"
i thought the solution would be {s/^/\1 - ABC-DEF /g}}" but that gave an error (invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS).

what is the solution to fill in the reference "1012" automatically or even better fill in the references "1012" - "ABC" - "DEF" automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[0-9]{4} - ABC-DEF/{p=$0;print;next}
     /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-/{p=""}$0=(p?p" ":"") $0' file
```

This one-liner read `2012-ABC-DEF` line and place it to the beginning of all lines till `2017-...(date)` line.

A little test:

```
kent$  cat f
foo
foo
1012 - ABC-DEF
VIP
Number
Index
Diagnosis
Variant
Hardware
2017-06-19 14:41:28
foo
foo

kent$  awk '/^[0-9]{4} - ABC-DEF/{p=$0;print;next}/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-/{p=""}$0=(p?p" ":"") $0' f
foo
foo
1012 - ABC-DEF
1012 - ABC-DEF VIP
1012 - ABC-DEF Number
1012 - ABC-DEF Index
1012 - ABC-DEF Diagnosis
1012 - ABC-DEF Variant
1012 - ABC-DEF Hardware
2017-06-19 14:41:28
foo
foo
```

Comment: thanks @kent for your answer, I'm a newbie and not familiar with awk can you or someone else produce the sed code?